# Composer - unable to autoload files

Tags: php, github, composer-php, codeigniter-3

I have a simple composer project on `GitHub` with the directory structure as:

```
/--
  -composer.json
  -lib/ComposerTest.php
```

with the `ComposerTest.php` file as:

```
namespace lib;

class ComposerTest{

    public function doTest(){
        return "This class was loaded from Composer\n";
    }
}
```

and `composer.json` as:

```
{
   "name":"sc/composerTest",
   "autoload":{
       "psr-0":{
           "lib":"./"
              }
        }

  }
```

Using the following `composer.json` file, I'm able to include the `GitHub` project into my `vendor` folder, but cannot get it to autoload.

```
{
   "description" : "The CodeIgniter Application with Composer",
       "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.2",
             "codeigniter/framework": "3.1.*",
             "kriswallsmith/buzz":"*",
             "maltyxx/bower": "^1.0",
             "sc/composerTest":"dev-master"
        },
         "require-dev": {
             "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*"
        },
         "repositories": [
               {
                 "type": "git",
                  "url": "https://github.com/sc/composerTest.git"
               }
           ]
       }
```

Can someone advise?

**Edit:** `ComposerTest` Controller

```
class ComposerTest extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       $composerTest = new ComposerTest();
       echo $composerTest->doTest();
     }
 }
```

Comment: When you run `composer install` or `composer update` do your see your `composerTest` package being installed? Is it present under the `vendor/` folder?

Comment: Yeah, it's been installed and sitting in my `vendor` folder.  I get `error: call to undefined method` when I try to call `ComposerTest::doTest()` in a Controller

Comment: Forgot your Controller for a second. Show us a simple test php script in your local project that requires the composer autoload, and attempts to use `ComposerTest`.

Comment: Added Controller class

Comment: I don't see `use lib\ComposerTest` in your controller.

Comment: Enable autoload in config.php and use class before controller class. Also, change name of controller since CI3 classes don't use namespacing.

Comment: Thanks - got it working now!